# Yoast Plugin causes content to repeat multiple times

Tags: wordpress

I've run into an issue where a page's content repeats multiple times. This only happens on 1 page on my site. http://prntscr.com/99pn5s

Disabling Yoast SEO solves the issue, but disabling the plugin really isn't an acceptable long term solution.

If anyone has run into a similar situation, I would appreciate any help on how to prevent this content from being repeated, or knowing what causes this.

Here is the rendered HTML markup: http://pastebin.com/Xbi0ce6Z

Comment: I see something very strange in the source code: there's *lots* of HTML data in the `<head>` section, specifically in the Yoast section. Check lines 20-456. Do you have any idea why does that come from?

Comment: There is a custom plugin that places that content on the page. Not sure how it injects it into the page, but that may be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add any html to the yoast fields? If you are using visual editor try switching to the text editor to see if any html was added accedently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer behind the custom plugin.

After some digging, I find out:

Yoast SEO plugin will use `get_the_excerpt` as `og:description` and it'll [output](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/6744d2dccd7593caea97e96bc7f1a70c83d5f73e/frontend/class-opengraph.php#L530) it by default.

the default filter of `get_the_excerpt`: `wp_trim_excerpt` will use `the_content` as excerpt when post doesn't have a native excerpt.

my solution is disable the `get_the_excerpt` in that particular page.